# Autocomplete for Play 2.0 views paths in Scala controllers in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, autocomplete, playframework-2.0

This is a visual reference to the google group discussion:  https://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/14660fd7056d577e/a3afb4ca06d25ce5#a3afb4ca06d25ce5

So, I'm simply trying to add some verbosity to views:

[image]

When I reference either of the files, or try to, in the Scala controller, based on the example provided in the Google Group, I get an error:

[image]

[image]

What gives?

Comment: I have been experiencing the same think and look forward to getting this resolved as well.

Comment: @chopps: Then, you should upvote the question, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** *I'm not a Eclipse user, just created and imported blank Play's project to check this issue! I had no time to test Eclipse configs, just imported as descriped at Play's docs. Maybe it is some way to better configuration, but you need search for it yourself :)*

I wouldn't blame Play, it does its job properly, otherwise it wouldn't compile at all. As I wrote in Google Group's topic you need to place your view in package: `/views/nested/index.scala.html` (of course `nested` is just a some name it can be whatever else), then you can catch it with: `Ok(views.html.`**`nested.index()`**`)`

In Eclipse:

1. in `Package Explorer` click `views` package with: `right mouse button` > `New` > `Package` and write package's name `views.nested` or `views.one` or something else, even it could be: `views.nested.one.two.three`
2. Add new view into this package `myNewView.scala.html`
3. Run any request in browser (to let the Play compile new views), optionally you can run Play with command `play ~run` so it will compile your new or changed views right after saving in IDE.
4. in Eclipse menu choose `Project` > `Clean...`. De facto, that's the clue, I'm not quite sure why this cleaning is required as Play compiles everything properly, read the disclaimer at the beginning.
5. From now your Eclipse will see this new view(s)

**Screenshot**

[image]