# Eclipse thinks it can't find 3rd party JAR in PlayFramework 2.0

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've been using the PlayFramework for some small projects, whenever I've done this its all been through a text editor. I've now moved over to Eclipse. I followed the commands to generate Eclipse project settings etc.

Everything seems to work fine. However, one 3rd party library, which I've added to referenced libs and put inside the \libs dir is throwing a 'cannot resolve type' error in Eclipse.

But when I run the project, everything works just fine. So the error is nothing more than an annoyance, and its the type of annoyance that really bothers me! So can anyone please tell me how I fix this.

Comment: Could you please post a snapshot of the error and the Java Build Path (Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries) ?

Comment: Most probably it;s the same topic as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458461/autocomplete-for-play-2-0-views-paths-in-scala-controllers-in-eclipse

Comment: Please show the generated `.classpath` and tell us the name of the missing library.